# boss has feeling for an employee, and she is keeping her job

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

My husband and I own a business and he has feeling for one of our employees. He told her so in a chat message that she then sent to me. I had noticed that they where getting closer but did not say anything to them. I thought I was overthinking it. She said she has no feelings for him. But she was overly friendly and flirty . So now I know and my husband and I have decided to do get help with our marriage. She still works for us, under the understand that she only works with me and never with him.  I now need to write a letter for all involved so I can protect our business from her suing us and our business, but im at a lose of  what to put in this letter. Could some one give me some help with this?

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow, but why she would sue your business? You didn't fire her or anything.

Comment: At the point that you are sufficiently concerned about a lawsuit to want to write a letter that protects your business from a suit, you really ought to visit an actual lawyer who can tell you what, if anything, you ought to be doing.  Much better to spend a couple hundred bucks today to get some guidance than to spend tens of thousands down the line because of some misstep.

Comment: This isn't really a Workplace matter, more of a legal issue.

Comment: Loss not lose and if you are worried about getting sued then consult an attorney.

Comment: @deviantfan I suspect the real question she wants to ask is "How do I fire this employee without getting sued?" and is assuming that writing a letter offers protection. Of course, the answer to this is also to get a lawyer.

Answer (score 4):

You should call an attorney, get an hourly rate, and if it seems reasonable, set up a meeting and discuss what you fear from the employee and what you hope to gain by writing this "letter".  And as was pointed out by @JoeStrazzere do this before sending any letter.

Worst case scenario would seem to be unethical attoreny charging you several hours of billable time for make work -- which would only seem likely if there wasn't in fact something they could have done that would have been more useful to you.  Which means you get relatively cheap reassurance...

Talk to a lawyer

Comment: Only an attorney can give you qualified legal advice about how to proceed in order to avoid a lawsuit.  But, you also need to have a serious heart-to-heart talk *(and, I mean that ...)* with your husband. Maybe, separately, you should speak with his lady-friend. Attorneys are also referred-to as *"Counselors,"* and with good reason.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I meant the worse thing that could happen **because** she talked to the lawyer.